# Show 50% mark line only only for today

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1rGv.png)

As seen in the screenshot, the green line is plotted to show the 50% mark from the close which usually is a resistance. I would like this to show this line just for today and doesn't extend backward because I don't care about the other days. How can this be done?

```
plot(CPreviousCloseone, color=color.new(color.green, 50))
```

I tried this code I found here on stackoverflow, but I am not in tech sector, I'm doing this as a must :D

```
isToday = false
if year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time) and dayofmonth(timenow) == dayofmonth(time) 
    isToday := true
plot(tdo,linewidth=1,color=isToday ? maroon : na)
```